# Remove artifact in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I have this 3D image where on top(below) there is a hemisphere(blue) and an inner cylinder(green), you can see there is some overlap/artifact being displayed. How can I remove this?

```
r = 0.5;
rbelow = 0.5;
dbelow = {0, 0, -1.5};
rabove = 0.5;
dabove = {0, 0, 1.5};
HemisphereBelow = ParametricPlot3D[rbelow {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + dbelow, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
HemisphereAbove = ParametricPlot3D[rabove {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + dabove, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, \[Pi]/2, 3 \[Pi]/2}, PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
InnerCylinder = ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], z}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -1.5, 1.5}, PlotPoints -> 25, PlotStyle -> Green, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleBelow = RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] - 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleAbove = RevolutionPlot3D[-Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] + 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.03, Black], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1.5}, {0, 0, 1.5}}, 1], Opacity[0.4, Green], InnerCylinder, Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereBelow, Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereAbove, Opacity[0.4, Red], QuarterCircleBelow, Opacity[0.4, Red], QuarterCircleAbove, Black, Thickness[0.005], Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}], Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 0, -0.10}, {0, 0, 0.10}}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just shift slightly the various elements e.g. `rbelow =0.49` ?

```
r = 0.5;
rbelow = 0.49;
dbelow = {0, 0, -1.5};
rabove = 0.49;
dabove = {0, 0, 1.5};
HemisphereBelow = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    rbelow {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + 
     dbelow, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
    PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> None][[1]];
HemisphereAbove = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
    rabove {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + 
     dabove, {u, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {v, \[Pi]/2, 3 \[Pi]/2}, 
    PlotPoints -> {25, 25}, PlotStyle -> Blue, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> None][[1]];
InnerCylinder = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[u], r Sin[u], z}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {z, -1.5,
      1.5}, PlotPoints -> 25, PlotStyle -> Green, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleBelow = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] - 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
QuarterCircleAbove = 
  RevolutionPlot3D[-Sqrt[0.5^2 - (r - 1)^2] + 1.5, {r, 0.5, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.03, Black], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1.5}, {0, 0, 1.5}}, 0.99], Opacity[0.4, Green], 
  InnerCylinder, Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereBelow, 
  Opacity[0.5, Blue], HemisphereAbove, Opacity[0.4, Red], 
  QuarterCircleBelow, Opacity[0.4, Red], QuarterCircleAbove, Black, 
  Thickness[0.005], Line[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}], Black, 
  PointSize[Large], Point[{{0, 0, -0.10}, {0, 0, 0.10}}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: What causes this to happen? Your answer is nice but it tries to avoid this problem for this specific problem only. Is there a general function/command that removes this?

Comment: I thought this arises from inconsistency in placements of (nearly) overlapping surfaces. But the Method option "RelieveDPZFighting"->True doesn't help in this case.

Comment: A simpler version of the problem: Graphics3D[{Green, InnerCylinder, Blue, HemisphereAbove}, 
 Boxed -> False]